# Deploy Azure web role from project with dynamic structure

Tags: azure, msbuild, webdeploy, csproj, azure-sdk-.net

I have a project with a buildable frontend. In my project there a lot of folders and files that should not be in target package and list of theese files depends on result of frontend compilation.
So i have some custom  tags in my source .csproj file (according
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171454.aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171455.aspx)

```
<Content Include="modules\**\*dist\**" Exclude="modules\**\node_modules\**"/>
<Content Include="modules\**\*bower_components\**\*.js;modules\**\*bower_components\**\*.css" Exclude="modules\**\node_modules\**"/>
<Content Include="modules\**\*js\**" Exclude="modules\**\node_modules\**"/>
<Content Include="Areas\Authentication\Content\static\**\*dist\**" Exclude="modules\**\node_modules\**"/>
<Content Include="Areas\Authentication\Content\static\**\*bower_components\**\*.js;Areas\Authentication\Content\static\**\*bower_components\**\*.css" Exclude="modules\**\node_modules\**"/>
<Content Include="Areas\Authentication\Content\static\**\*js\**" Exclude="modules\**\node_modules\**"/>
```

As a result i have needed output file structure in Visual Studio 2013 Solution Explorer included in project.

When I trying to deploy project to Azure (SDK 2.2) i have an error in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets like that

Error   2945    Unable to copy file "BlaBlaBla\Content\static***js**" to "BlaBlaBla\Areas\Authentication\Content\static***js**". Illegal characters in path.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.2\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets  2668    5

How I can use wildcard item definitions for Azure deployment?